# Retrieving active employees by month in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my employee database, I have a column `hire_date` which has the hiring date of an employee, and `deactivate_date` which has the date on which the employee was dismissed (or null if employee is still active).

To find the number of active employees at the beginning of any month, I can run the following query. For example, to see my active employees on 1st January 2019 -

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM employees
WHERE hire_date <= '2019-01-01' AND
(deactivate_date IS NULL OR deactivate_date > '2019-01-01')
```

Now, what I would like to know is the number of active employees on the 1st of every month of 2018. I can obviously run this query 12 times, but would like to know if there is a more efficient solution possible. It seems like the `CROSSTAB` and `generate_series` functions of pg will be useful, but I haven't been able to form the proper query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `generate_series()`:

```
SELECT gs.dte, count(e.hire_date) 
FROM generate_series('2018-01-01'::date, '2018-12-01'::date, interval '1 month') gs(dte) LEFT JOIN
     employees e
     ON e.hire_date <= gs.dte AND
        (e.deactivate_date IS NULL OR e.deactivate_date > gs.dte)
GROUP BY gs.dte
ORDER BY gs.dte;
```